# drop group by number of occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter, pandas-groupby

Hi I want to delete the rows with the entries whose number of occurrence is smaller than a number, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,2], 'b':[4,5,6,7], 'c':[0,1,3,2]})
df
```

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  0
1  2  5  1
2  3  6  3
3  2  7  2
```

Here I want to delete all the rows if the number of occurrence in column 'a' is less than twice.
Wanted output:

```
   a  b  c
1  2  5  1
3  2  7  2
```

What I know: 
we can find the number of occurrence by `condition = df['a'].value_counts() < 2`, and it will give me something like:

```
2    False
3    True
1    True
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

But I don't know how I should approach from here to delete the rows.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)

```
res = df[df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('size') >= 2]
```

The [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) method maps `df.groupby('a')['b'].size()` to `df` aligned with `df['a']`.

#### [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
s = df['a'].value_counts()
res = df[df['a'].map(s) >= 2]

print(res)

   a  b  c
1  2  5  1
3  2  7  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can use `df.where` and the `dropna`

```
df.where(df['a'].value_counts() <2).dropna()

     a   b   c
1   2.0 5.0 1.0
3   2.0 7.0 2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this to get the length of each group, transform back to original index and index the df by it

```
df[df.groupby("a").transform(len)["b"] >= 2]


    a   b   c
1   2   5   1
3   2   7   2
```

Breaking it into individual steps you get:

```
df.groupby("a").transform(len)["b"]

0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

These are the group sizes transformed back onto your original index

```
df.groupby("a").transform(len)["b"] >=2

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

We then turn this into the boolean index and index our original dataframe by it